# Extracting plus (+), minus (-), and period (.) characters and all numbers [0-9] from a character string in R

Tags: regex, r, string, perl, vector

I have many character strings that look like this, with a large variance of numbers:

```
tester1 <- "{\"fullgame\":\"-303\"}"

tester2 <- "{\"fullgame\":\"+7.5\"}"
```

I would like to extract plus(+), minus(-), and period(.) characters, along with all numbers[0-9] from my strings.  I would also like to preserve the current order of each of these elements as they appear in the string.

I want the resulting strings to be:

```
formatted1 = "-303"

formatted2 = "+7.5"
```

I know that functions like `gsub`, `strsplit`, and `regex` would be ideal for this application, but for the life of me, I can't figure out the Perl syntax =(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you guys!

Comment: do you want to extract them into a single new string?

Comment: [`[+-][.0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/aQ6sW9/1). It may suit you.

Comment: which perl syntax you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strings look like `json` a lot. See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for more info. You shouldn't try to parse them with `regex`; rely instead on a specific `json` parser. There are many in `R`. Extracting the desired quantity is as easy as:

```
require(jsonlite) #other libraries: rjson, RJSONIO
fromJSON(tester1)
#$fullgame
#[1] "+7.5"
```

Comment: Thank you nicola!  I'm somewhat new to R and programming in general, so I did not catch that this may be `json`. I appreciate your help with this matter.

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider accepting/upvoting the answer, if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "Perl" but this regex pattern pulls your numbers out:

```
> gsub( "([^-+]+)([+-]{0,1}[0-9.]+)(.+)", "\\2", c(tester1,tester2) )
[1] "-303" "+7.5"
```

Breaking apart the `pattern` which has three capture sections:

```
([^-+]+)  : uses the negation operator in a character class to match any sequence that is
            not a plus or minus sign
([+-]{0,1}[0-9.]+) : the second capture class allows (but does not require) a single 
            +/- sign, followed by any number of digits or decimal point/period
(.+) : is the third capture class ... anything else that is trailing
```

This one is a bit more specific about what form the numbers and decimal points can assume by adding optional single decimal point and subsequent digits:

```
gsub( "([^-+]+)([+-]{0,1}[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]*)(.+)", "\\2", c(tester1,tester2) )
```

I'm pretty sure that there are earlier postings that covered extraction of signed decimal numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have seen many postings that had similar sequences for gsub, however, they did not all include the plus(+), minus(-) and period(.) signs.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can `gsub` out anything that doesn't match the type of characters you're looking for:

```
gsub('[^+-.0-9]', '', tester1)
# [1] "-303"
gsub('[^+-.0-9]', '', tester2)
# [1] "+7.5"
```

`[^ ... ]` defines a set of characters `...` where the `^` tells it to match anything except for them. `gsub` then replaces all those characters with nothing, leaving you with what you want.